# Validate textbox to a column of a table in a database LIKE LOGIN FORMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, validation

How to do you validate a textbox entered value is valid before shooting or running q query?? You know like Emails or login or registration forms where it can check if the email exists in the database or not.?? How do you make this in ASP.NET??

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5z00s5e

This is the nearest tutorial I found about it!! But I didnt really get it. So anybody can help me please??

for ex:

I have a textbox (txt_checkemail)

a table called (employees) with a column (username), the textbox must validate that the email inserted exits inside the column username.

Please help!!

Comment: does it answer your question???

Comment: Is it possible with validation?? Im actually trying now with it, and seeing if it works!!

Comment: It is a validation method

Comment: I meant custom validation or some type of validation inside the toolbox

Comment: As far as I know: no...

Comment: Okay I have tried it on a code for database but it didnt work. At [validateemail] should I put a query inside a dataset or datatable or should I put it in sqlcommand and execute it/???

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control.

**Form Code**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" 
            onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (ValidateEmail(txtEmail.Text))
            args.IsValid = true; 
        else
            args.IsValid = false;
    }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
        //Carry on
    else
       //Validator has failed, ask user to correct.
}
```

Comment: You could write that inside the ValidateEmail method (or whatever you want to call it). The code just needs to exist with the ServerValidate event and then either set args.IsValid to true (if the email was valid) or false (if it failed). The Page.IsValid call in the Button1 Click then checks whether or not the page has passed validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this event:

```
private void txt_checkemail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var isValid = ValidateEmail(txt_checkemail.Text);

   if (isValid)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("The emailadress you've entered is valid!");
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("The emailadress you've entered is NOT valid!");
   }
}

private bool ValidateEmail(object valueToCheck)
{
    //execute query on the database to check if the value entered in the textbox is valid.
}
```

Or you can use a button which if you click on it, it will check if the value entered in the textbox is valid or not.